# How to get Base64 string from sql database to itextsharp pdf report

Tags: c#, pdf, base64, itext

I have a signature canvas that saves the output (Base64 string) directly into my sql database. i am failing to get the Base64 string and show it as an image in the output iTextsharp pdf file.

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {                
            string query = "SELECT TechnicianSignature, CustomerSignature FROM OnSiteWorkTx";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
```

I am stuck at loading the above into the dataset.

Comment: You fail on _where_? Any exception or error message? Don't you already fill your `DataSet` with `da.Fill(ds);`?

Comment: I can't help you getting a Base64 string from a database, but once you have that string, you can use iText Base64 class to convert that String to its original format (I assume it's an image). Once you have that image, you can use `Image.getInstance()`. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/Base64.html (You need the `decode()` method.)

Comment: i mean to say after it has been filled how to call them

Comment: At this point you don't have an iTextSharp related problem, right? You're stuck at getting an string-based image from a database?